# Missing required parameters for [Route: utente.show] [URI: registrazione/{utente}]

Tags: php, laravel

hi I created a form inside the view `create_registrazione.blade.php`, with fields `'email'` and `'password'` and when I press the `'accedi'` button it should take me to the user's page, (obviously email, password and username are present in a database), but when I press the `'accedi'` button, 
I get this error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: utente.show] [URI: registrazione/{utente}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\boxe\resources\views\registrazione\create_registrazione.blade.php)
```

below the code:

ROUTES:

```
Route::get('/registrazione','RegistrazioniController@create')->name('registrazione.create');

Route::post('/registrazione/store','RegistrazioniController@store')->name('registrazione.store');

Route::get('/registrazione/{utente}','RegistrazioniController@show')->name('utente.show');
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function create(tabella_utenti $utente)
{

    return view('registrazione.create_registrazione',compact('utente'));
}

//2(salvataggio dati nel DB)
public function store(tabella_utenti $utente)
{
    $this->validate (request(),[
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'NomeUtente' => 'required'
    ]);
    $utente=tabella_utenti::create(request(['email','password','NomeUtente']));
    //richiamo l'id dell'utente
    $utenteId=$utente->id;
    return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utenteId')));

}

public function show(tabella_utenti $utente)
{
    return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utente')));
}
```

VIEW:

```
<!--form accesso-->
<div style="display: none; margin-left: 550px" id="form2">
    <h2 style="color: red">Accedi</h2>
    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'utente.show',$utente->id]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email','Email',['style'=>'h3']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('email','',['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:220px','placeholder'=>'Inserisci@la mail']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password','Password',['style'=>'h3']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('password','',['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width:220px','placeholder'=>'inserisci la password' ]) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form:: submit('accedi',['class'=>' btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('homepage')}}"> home </a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
return redirect(route('utente.show',['utente'=>$utenteId]));
```

instead of what you're doing now:

```
return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utenteId')));
```

If you're using laravel 5.5+ than you should be good to go with this only:

```
// $utenteId=$utente->id;
return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utente')));
```

Edited:

Well the issue than is about route model bindings.

Solutions:

1. Renaming your variable from `utente` to `user` and that should work.

   ```
   Route::get('/registrazione/{user}','RegistrazioniController@show')->name('utente.show');
   ```
2. In your controller you may do this:

   ```
   public function show(tabella_utenti $utente)
   {
        $utente = tabella_utenti::find($utente); //Since $utente is just the user id here
        return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utente')));
   }
   ```
3. Third way is creating custom route model binding.

   In RouteServiceProvider.php, you may add this:

   ```
   public function boot()
   {
       parent::boot();

       Route::model( 'utente', tabella_utenti::class);
   }
   ```

For more information check [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: the problem is not with the store function, if you look better my view is connected to the show function ..

Comment: and the error that return is that:Missing required parameters for [Route: utente.show] [URI: registrazione/{utente}].

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your redirect. Please have a look at the [Routing official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) for more insights. You have to change your code from

```
return redirect(route('utente.show',compact('utenteId')));
```

to:

```
return redirect()->route('utente.show',['utente' => $utenteId]);
```

to make it work. Beacuse your route `/registrazione/{utente}` wants 'utente' as parameter, but `compact` function will return an array like `['utenteId' => 1]`, that's why it's throwing the `Missing required parameters` error

Comment: i did,but returned the same error,the problem is in the show method,look:

Comment: Maybe the controller is not the only one with that wrong route generation... Check also in view and other parts of the code

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: utente.show] [URI: registrazione/{utente}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\boxe\resources\views\registrazione\create_registrazione.blade.php)

Comment: i wrote in the function show this code:    public function show(tabella_utenti $utente)
    {
        $utenteId=$utente->id;
        return redirect(route('utente.show',['utente' => $utenteId]));
    }
..but return the same error

Comment: I've updated my code... I saw an error.. Anyway... There may be other parts of code where you call wrong routes...

Comment: Also... In your code `{!! Form::open(['route'=>'utente.show',$utente->id]) !!}` you're not submitting the form to `utente.show` route, but `store` route